# How to reactively and repeatedly render the same type of object with an action button in R shiny?

Tags: r, function, shiny, module, shiny-reactivity

The code at the bottom is taken from an example in https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html though I de-modularized it so I can understand something more basic. With this code, each click of the action button renders a counter which counts the number of clicks. Fine.

Instead of counting the number of clicks in the same output of `verbatimTextOutput()` as the code currently works, I'd like each click to be represented as a new output of `verbatimTextOutput()`. See illustration below which shows what I'm trying to derive, assuming the user clicks the action button 3 times. I don't know how many times the user will click the action button so there's no way to pre-set or hard-code the number of outputs and assign output names such as `output$out1`, `output$output2`, etc. Is there a way to reactively generate the outputs names, as a I naively attempted in the below code with `output$"paste(out,count())"` and `verbatimTextOutput("paste(out,count())")` (without the quote marks, I only put them in so the example code would work)? If this is possible this could be a way to achieve the results I am seeking.

Illustration:

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)

newOutput <- function(x,y){verbatimTextOutput("paste(out,count())")}

ui <- fluidPage(uiOutput("uiButton"))

server <- function(input,output,session){
  count <- reactiveVal(0)
  observeEvent(input$button, {count(count() + 1)})
  output$"paste(out,count())" <- renderText({count()})
  count
  
  output$uiButton <-
    renderUI(
      tagList(
        actionButton("button", label = "Click me"),
        newOutput()
      )
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I posted another approach below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an alternative approach using `insertUI`.

Compared to @stefan's `renderUI` based solution it has the advantage, that the UI elements are rendered only once. Using `renderUI` every element is re-rendered on button click, accordingly things will slow down depending on the number of elements.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "Add UI")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    output_name <- paste0("out_", input$add)
    output[[output_name]] <- renderText({
      isolate(input$add)
    })
    insertUI(
      selector = ifelse(input$add == 0L, "#add", paste0("#", "out_", input$add-1)),
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = verbatimTextOutput(output_name)
    )
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Also check `?removeUI`.

[image: result]

Comment: This is the first time I hear of `insertUI`. Interesting. In reality there would be no more than 10-15 UI additions max so I don't think speed is much of a concern.

Comment: @Village.Idyot it is not only a matter of the element count. You might be rendering more complex / bigger elements which add up more rendering time than simple text elements. My general advice is: stay away from `renderUI` wherever you can.

Comment: Ah yes, I recall you advised that when I first started with R and I moved away from `renderUI`. I initially misread your answer: `insertUI` has the advantage that the UI elements are rendered only once. I misread it thinking `renderUI` has that advantage.

Comment: Much better than my approach. Realized the issue but still have much to learn about shiny. :D

Answer (score 1):

Adapting this [example](https://tbradley1013.github.io/2018/08/10/create-a-dynamic-number-of-ui-elements-in-shiny-with-purrr/) to dynamically create graphs to your example you could do:

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)

newOutput <- function(x) {
  verbatimTextOutput(x)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("button", label = "Click me"),
  uiOutput("uiText")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  count <- reactiveVal(0)
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    count(count() + 1)
    i <- count()
    output_name <- paste("out", i)
    output[[output_name]] <- renderText({
      i
    })
  })

  output$uiText <- renderUI({
    out_list <- map(seq_len(count()), ~ {
      tagList(
        newOutput(paste("out", .x))
      )
    })
    tagList(out_list)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful. I now understand one of the uses for purrr. Going through the link in your answer "purrr has applications in pretty much any situation. One of the most useful situations...is in the creation of a dynamic number of shiny UI elements. This can be extremely useful if you want to be able to create a dynamic number of ui elements (whether that be inputs or outputs) based on either user selection or the data being used."

Comment: @Village.Idyot there is no need for purrr here - the same can be done with e.g. `lapply` / `sapply`.